# iOS ARKit + RealityKit: On object occlusion methods that work for fast moving objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, realitykit

I am creating an iOS ARKit + RealityKit App with object occlusion.

So, I tried the following program code.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        
        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)
        
        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Occlusion worked well for stationary objects, but not for fast-moving objects.

Is there a method of occlusion that works for fast moving objects like AR Foundation's automatic environment occlusion?